# Ajustar visualização de uma aplicação independente da resolução do monitor

Tags: java, javafx

Fiz uma aplicação `Java` e percebi que quando roda em um computador com resolução mais alta, ela fica pequena. Como ajustar visualização de uma aplicação independente da resolução do monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o tamanho da tela com o método `Toolkit.getScreenSize()`.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

Em uma configuração para vários monitores você deve usar este:

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Se você quer pegar o a resolução em DPI vc pode usar o metodo `getScreenResolution()` da classe `Toolkit`.

**Referencias:**
[javadoc - Toolkit.getScreenSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29)
No Linux pode ocorrer um bug tem um [fix aqui](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5100801)!

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Herbert, sou fraco nesse assunto. Não sei como implementar isso no código.

Comment: Consegui... valeu.